# Sync contact with a JSONArray in sqlite

Tags: android, contacts

I have a JSONArray in SQLite database from my previous contacts, 
now i want to listen for add, remove, update contacts and make JSONObject from new contacts and push them in my JSONArray,

is there any way ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite database there is no a data type call "JSONArray" or "JSONObject".
Refer to: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

So, firstly, you should create a database table for store your data which defined in the JSONArray, for example, if you want to save a list of user contact that you should design a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
Mobile int(20)
);
```

And then breakdown the array to objects and save to database field by field.

NOTE!! Don't just save the JSONArray to a database's field as a long long String directly, because it's very very lazy, and meaningless to use database.

In Android, there are some useful libraries can help you do this job. Try to learn using annotation in java programming:

1. Gson - help you convert the JSON to an Java object. https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide
2. Ormlite - help you manage, edit and update the database in Android. 
   http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml